# Pass column name to lpSolve obj from drop down

Tags: r, shiny, lpsolve

Pass column name to lpSolve obj from drop down.

OptTotal total is a column name for optimisation, I would like a drop down box to select which column to optimise against but can not figure it out.

```
  obj <- rv$products$OptTotal
```

I would like something like the below

obj <- rv$products$get(Input$ColumnName)  This does not work but explains what I would like.

Comment: Are you looking for `obj <- rv$products[["OptTotal"]]`? If you want to pass a column name to a function, use `[[`, not `$`.

Comment: This works fine obj <- rv$products$OptTotal  where OptTotal  is the column name but I want to select the column name from a drop down box.  obj to passed to this:   result <- lp("max", obj, con(), dir, rhs$const, all.bin = TRUE)

Comment: Maybe with an auxiliary function. Pass the column name to that function, extract the vector `obj` with `[[` and pass the vector to `lp`.

Comment: This is in a shiny app, is the syntax different?

Comment: @daffer What's the problem with `obj <- rv$products[[input$ColumnName]]`?